# Is the phrase 'on the bottom floor' an idiom?

Tags: idioms

I'm not convinced whether asking this question in here is right or not. But I think the phrase 'on the bottom floor' MAY BE a kind of idioms. I guess it means 'to succeed in' So, I write the question in here.

During the day, Brain attended shcool, and at night to support himself, he was a waiter at a downtown diner. On a good night, Brian brought home about $90 in tips. During a period of three years, Brian saved almost $1,200. One day at lunch, Brain's friend, Lance, told him about a startup company in Canada. "If you get in now," lance said, "**you'll be in on the bottom floor.** You'll make at least three times your money in only a couple of weeks."

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a variant of the idiom ["to get in on the ground floor."](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+in+on+the+ground+floor)  It means to be involved in something at the very earliest stages, with the implication that you'll get some advantage by being there before anyone else.  It's typically used to refer to investments, to suggest to potential investors that this is going to be the next big thing, and that they'd be a fool not to invest.

I've only ever heard "ground floor" for the idiom; this is the first time I've seen it as "bottom floor," and so it took me a little while to recognize it.  But the context makes it clear.  [Ngrams shows hardly any results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ground%20floor%2C%20bottom%20floor&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cground%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bground%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGround%20Floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGround%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGROUND%20FLOOR%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbottom%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbottom%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBottom%20floor%3B%2Cc0) for "bottom floor" compared to "ground floor."